# Programmatically determine serial port from printing w/o using port monitoring tools in Python

Tags: python, c++, winapi, logging, printing

**Why?**

- I need to automate the setup of serial port monitoring for only the printer port that it uses.

**What makes this difficult...**

- The device is already in use so opening the port to print something is not a solution(ie. pyserial)
- I cannot assume the user is capable of identifying the correct port.
- I cannot install other software to do this.

**What is possible**

- Prompting the user to print something.

**Possible solutions**

- Use System.IO.Device to monitor activity
- Create a windows event that logs printing activity
- Monitor for printing activity from the PCI Bus
- Register a windows device event that notifies activity

Comment: Is the printer the only device using a serial port? Is there only one printer?

Comment: There could be other devices using different serial ports, but only the printer will be using that port. @PeterGibson